# PHP variables not working with load function

Tags: php, variables

This works fine in when using echo/print:

```
<?php echo ('http://test.com/%%CENTER_NAME_LINK%%/feed/'); ?>
```

But when I use **load**, which I need, it does not add in the variable:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss-> load ('http://test.com/%%CENTER_NAME_LINK%%/feed/');
$feed = array(); ...
```

Here's the setup:

```
$center_name_link = $center['center_name'];
$center_name_link = str_replace(' ', '-', $center_name_link);
$center_name_link = strtolower($center_name_link);
$html = str_replace('%%CENTER_NAME_LINK%%', $center_name_link, $html);
```

**How can I get the load to work with the variable?!**  I've tried using ' . $center_name_link . ', but that does not show up in either echo/print or load. I've tried creating a variable with the link already in it. I've tried a lot of other things, but I just can't get it to work out...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes when you want to add a variable into a string
eg

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load ("http://test.com/$CENTER_NAME_LINK/feed/"); // NOTE $ sign
$feed = array(); ..
```

You can also add variables with the dot operate eg .

$rss->load ("http://test.com/".$CENTER_NAME_LINK."/feed/"); // NOTE . between varialbe and text

Comment: Thanks, John! I've tried both of those recommendations, but they both come up blank (AKA http://test.com//feed) both using echo and load. The only thing that seems to work with echo is HTML defined parameter - %%CENTER_NAME_LINK%%. But this does not work with load. Do you happen to have any more suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Use double quotes.
echo out the $center_name_link variable on its own so you are sure that is working.